# Raycasting algorithm in pygame

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pygame, raycasting

For the past week, I've been developing a simple raycasting algorithm. And I've finally managed to work out how to add textures and to get everything working.as I'd like it to. However, even at a rather low resolution of 5 pixels per vertical scan line, the program still runs incredibly slowly. It runs a bit better in fullscreen mode, as here the mouse input works properly, but it's still really bad.

It ran smoothly before I added the textures, and just had plain colour, even at a resolution of 1 pixel per vertical scan line. But the game is nearly unplayable now. So I want to know how I can optimize my code to make the program run faster?

I'd also like it if somebody would review the code normally so that I can improve it further.

Here is my code:

```
import sys, os, pygame, time
from pygame.locals import *
from math import *

####------Colours------####
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
BLUE      = (  0,   0, 255)
BROWN     = (139,  69,  19)
CYAN      = (  0, 255, 255)
DARKBLUE  = (  0,   0,  64)
DARKBROWN = ( 36,  18,   5)
DARKGREEN = (  0,  64,   0)
DARKGREY  = ( 64,  64,  64)
DARKRED   = ( 64,   0,   0)
GREY      = (128, 128, 128)
GREEN     = (  0, 128,   0)
LIME      = (  0, 255,   0)
MAGENTA   = (255,   0, 255)
MAROON    = (128,   0,   0)
NAVYBLUE  = (  0,   0, 128)
OLIVE     = (128, 128,   0)
PURPLE    = (128,   0, 128)
RED       = (255,   0,   0)
SILVER    = (192, 192, 192)
TEAL      = (  0, 128, 128)
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW    = (255, 255,   0)
####-------------------####

pygame.init()

path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'data')

WIDTH    = 1360
HEIGHT   = 768
map_size = int((WIDTH / 680) * 64)

CLOCK    = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS      = 60
SCREEN   = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pygame.display.set_caption("Raycaster")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

map_colour     = MAROON
floor_colour   = DARKBROWN
ceiling_colour = DARKRED

rotate_speed   = 0.01
move_speed     = 0.05
strafe_speed   = 0.04
wall_height    = 1.27
resolution     = 6 #Pixels per line

texture   = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, 'Blood Wall Dark.bmp'))
texWidth  = texture.get_width()
texHeight = texture.get_height()
texArray  = pygame.PixelArray(texture)

HUD = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, 'HUD.png'))
HUD = pygame.transform.scale(HUD, (int(HUD.get_width() * (map_size / 64)), int(HUD.get_height() * (map_size / 64))))

old = 0

def create_level(file):
    if file[-4:] != '.txt': file += '.txt'
    f = open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r')
    file = f.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        file[i] = list(line.rstrip('\n'))
        for j, char in enumerate(file[i]):
            if char == ' ': file[i][j] = 0
            else:           file[i][j] = int(char)
    f.close()

    mapBoundX  = len(file)
    mapBoundY  = len(file[0])
    mapGrid    = []

    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        mapGrid.append([])
        for j, char in enumerate(file[i]):
            if char != 0:
                mapGrid[i].append(char)
            else:
                mapGrid[i].append(0)

    return mapBoundX, mapBoundY, mapGrid

def Quit():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def main():
    mapBoundX, mapBoundY, mapGrid = create_level('Level')

    posX, posY     = 8.5, 10.5
    dirX, dirY     = 1.0, 0.0
    planeX, planeY = 0.0, 0.66

    while True:

        #Input handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                Quit()
                return
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    Quit()
                    return

        #CEILING AND FLOOR
        pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, ceiling_colour, (0,                       0, WIDTH, (HEIGHT - map_size) / 2))
        pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN,   floor_colour, (0, (HEIGHT - map_size) / 2, WIDTH, (HEIGHT - map_size) / 2))

        for x in range(0, WIDTH, resolution):
            #Initial setup
            cameraX    = 2 * x / WIDTH - 1
            rayPosX    = posX
            rayPosY    = posY
            rayDirX    = dirX + planeX * cameraX + 0.000000000000001 #Add small value to avoid division by 0
            rayDirY    = dirY + planeY * cameraX + 0.000000000000001 #Add small value to avoid division by 0

            #Which square on the map the ray is in
            mapX = int(rayPosX)
            mapY = int(rayPosY)

            #The length of one ray from one x-side or y-side to the next x-side or y-side
            deltaDistX = sqrt(1 + rayDirY ** 2 / rayDirX ** 2)
            deltaDistY = sqrt(1 + rayDirX ** 2 / rayDirY ** 2)
            zBuffer    = []

            #Calculate step and initial sideDist
            if rayDirX < 0:
                stepX = -1
                sideDistX = (rayPosX - mapX) * deltaDistX
            else:
                stepX = 1
                sideDistX = (mapX + 1 - rayPosX) * deltaDistX

            if rayDirY < 0:
                stepY = -1
                sideDistY = (rayPosY - mapY) * deltaDistY
            else:
                stepY = 1
                sideDistY = (mapY + 1 - rayPosY) * deltaDistY

            #Digital differential analysis (DDA)
            while True:
                #Jump to next map square
                if sideDistX < sideDistY:
                    sideDistX += deltaDistX
                    mapX += stepX
                    side = 0
                else:
                    sideDistY += deltaDistY
                    mapY += stepY
                    side = 1

                #Check if ray hits wall or leaves the map boundries 
                if mapX >= mapBoundX or mapY >= mapBoundY or mapX < 0 or mapY < 0 or mapGrid[mapX][mapY] > 0:
                    break

            #Calculate the total length of the ray
            if side == 0: rayLength = (mapX - rayPosX + (1 - stepX) / 2) / rayDirX
            else:         rayLength = (mapY - rayPosY + (1 - stepY) / 2) / rayDirY

            #Calculate the length of the line to draw on the screen
            lineHeight = (HEIGHT / rayLength) * wall_height

            #Calculate the start and end point of each line
            drawStart  = -lineHeight / 2 + (HEIGHT - map_size) / 2
            drawEnd    =  lineHeight / 2 + (HEIGHT - map_size) / 2

            #Calculate where exactly the wall was hit
            if side == 0: wallX = rayPosY + rayLength * rayDirY
            else:         wallX = rayPosX + rayLength * rayDirX
            wallX = abs((wallX - floor(wallX)) - 1)

            #Find the x coordinate on the texture
            texX = int(wallX * texWidth)
            if side == 0 and rayDirX > 0: texX = texWidth - texX - 1
            if side == 1 and rayDirY < 0: texX = texWidth - texX - 1

            for y in range(texHeight):
                #Ignore pixels that are off of the screen
                if drawStart + (lineHeight / texHeight) * (y + 1) < 0: continue
                if drawStart + (lineHeight / texHeight) * y > HEIGHT - map_size: break

                #Load pixel's colour from array
                colour = pygame.Color(texArray[texX][y])

                #Darkens environment with distance
                c = 255.0 - abs(int(rayLength * 32)) * 0.85
                if c < 1:   c = 1
                if c > 255: c = 255

                #Different faces have different luminence to add to the 3D effect
                if side == 1: c = c * 0.75

                #Change the luminence if necessary
                new_colour = []
                for i, value in enumerate(colour):
                    if i == 0: continue #Exclude the alpha value
                    new_colour.append(value * (c / 255))
                colour = tuple(new_colour)

                pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, colour, (x, drawStart + (lineHeight / texHeight) * y), (x, drawStart + (lineHeight / texHeight) * (y + 1)), resolution)

        #Render the HUD
        SCREEN.blit(HUD, (0, HEIGHT - map_size))

        #Mini map            
        for x in range(mapBoundX):
            for y in range(mapBoundY):
                if mapGrid[y][x] != 0: pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, map_colour, ((x * (map_size / mapBoundX) + WIDTH) - map_size, y * (map_size / mapBoundY) + HEIGHT - map_size, (map_size / mapBoundX), (map_size / mapBoundY)))

        pos_on_map = (posY * (map_size / mapBoundY) + WIDTH - map_size, posX * (map_size / mapBoundX) + HEIGHT - map_size)

        #Draw player on mini map
        pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (  0, 255,   0), pos_on_map + (2, 2))
        pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, (255,   0, 127), pos_on_map, ((dirY + posY + planeY) * (map_size / mapBoundY) + WIDTH - map_size, (dirX + posX + planeX) * (map_size / mapBoundX) + HEIGHT - map_size))
        pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, (255,   0, 127), pos_on_map, ((dirY + posY - planeY) * (map_size / mapBoundY) + WIDTH - map_size, (dirX + posX - planeX) * (map_size / mapBoundY) + HEIGHT - map_size))
        pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, (255,   0, 127), ((dirY + posY + planeY) * (map_size / mapBoundY) + WIDTH - map_size, (dirX + posX + planeX) * (map_size / mapBoundX) + HEIGHT - map_size), ((dirY + posY - planeY) * (map_size / mapBoundY) + WIDTH - map_size, (dirX + posX - planeX) * (map_size / mapBoundY) + HEIGHT - map_size))

        #Movement controls
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_w]:
            if not mapGrid[int(posX + dirX * move_speed)][int(posY)]: posX += dirX * move_speed
            if not mapGrid[int(posX)][int(posY + dirY * move_speed)]: posY += dirY * move_speed

        if keys[K_a]:
            if not mapGrid[int(posX + dirY * strafe_speed)][int(posY)]: posX += dirY * strafe_speed
            if not mapGrid[int(posX)][int(posY - dirX * strafe_speed)]: posY -= dirX * strafe_speed

        if keys[K_s]:
            if not mapGrid[int(posX - dirX * move_speed)][int(posY)]: posX -= dirX * move_speed
            if not mapGrid[int(posX)][int(posY - dirY * move_speed)]: posY -= dirY * move_speed

        if keys[K_d]:
            if not mapGrid[int(posX - dirY * strafe_speed)][int(posY)]: posX -= dirY * strafe_speed
            if not mapGrid[int(posX)][int(posY + dirX * strafe_speed)]: posY += dirX * strafe_speed

        #Look left and right
        #Mouse input
        difference = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - (WIDTH / 2)
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2])

        #Keyboard input
        if keys[K_q]: difference = -5
        if keys[K_e]: difference = 5

        #Vector rotation
        if difference != 0:
            cosrot = cos(difference * rotate_speed)
            sinrot = sin(difference * rotate_speed)
            old    = dirX
            dirX   = dirX * cosrot - dirY * sinrot
            dirY   = old  * sinrot + dirY * cosrot
            old    = planeX
            planeX = planeX * cosrot - planeY * sinrot
            planeY = old    * sinrot + planeY * cosrot

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__=="__main__": main()
```

Here are the two images that I'm using to test the program for those interested:

**HUD.png**

[image: HUD.png]

**Blood Wall Dark.bmp**

[image: Blood Wall Dark.bmp]

The file Level.txt contains 256 1's and spaces in a 16x16 configuration, with the 1's as the walls and the spaces as the gaps. But the code does work with any sized grid. The `create_level()`  converts this file into a list.

Here is the contents of the file that I am using:

```
1111111111111111
1     11       1
1 111 11 11 11 1
1 1       1 11 1
1 1 1       1  1
1 1 111  11    1
1 1      1111  1
1   1  11   11 1
1 1         1  1
1 1    11   1  1
1 1  1   1 111 1
1 1   11     1 1
1 1        1 1 1
1 11 1     1   1
1    1        11
1111111111111111
```

The folder structure has the program in one directory, with the images and text file in a subdirectory called data like as shown:

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: I haven't read all your code, but you're trying to implement a slow algorithm, without a GPU, in JITless, interpreted Python, without any libraries like NumPy that people use when they need to do serious math in Python. Of course it'll be slow.

Comment: @user2357112 Is there a way of using the GPU in my computer to do this?

Comment: OpenGL? DirectX? CUDA? There are Python bindings for all those, if you want to stick to Python.

Comment: You should profile your code to find the bottlenecks: `python -m cProfile mygame.py`

Comment: @Caridorc is there a way of doing this in Idle, or would I have to open the command line to do it?

Comment: `import cProfile ...
cProfile.run('main()')`

Comment: We need a level file for this to be runnable. Can you add one to the question, please?

Comment: @GarethRees All of the necessary information to run the code is now available, you should be able to have a look at it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Raycaster]

Python is not a fast language — it trades execution speed for flexibility and introspectability — and the kind of repetitive numerical computation involved in CPU rendering is pretty much the worst case for Python. It would make much more sense to use a 3D rendering toolkit like [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/).

But so long as we understand that this is just an exercise, there are bound to be some improvements we can make. An important step is to measure the framerate so that we can be sure we're making improvements and not just fiddling with code. Here's code for an [exponentially weighted moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing):

```
average_frame = 1000 / FPS
while True:
    # ...
    average_frame *= 0.9
    average_frame += 0.1 * CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    print(1000 / average_frame)
```

On my computer I find that the game runs at about 18 fps.

The first step in speeding this up is to understand where all the time is going. In comments, [Caridorc suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159943/raycasting-algorithm-in-pygame#comment303065_159943) that you might use the profiler to figure this out. But the structure of the code makes it clear that the biggest fraction of the runtime is going to be spent in this loop (over the pixels in a column in a texture):

```
 for y in range(texHeight):
```

So instead of looping over the pixels in the column and drawing each pixel using `pygame.draw.line`, let's extract the column from the texture as a surface, colour-multiply it to apply the lighting effects, scale it, and blit it onto the screen.

This involves a couple of changes elsewhere in the code:

1. Convert the texture to RGB after loading it:

   ```
   texture = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, 'Blood Wall Dark.bmp'))
   texture = texture.convert()
   ```
2. Don't create the `PixelArray` (this locks the texture, and we won't be needing it any more).

Then, for each column:

1. Compute the part of the screen that we're going to draw to:

   ```
   yStart = max(0, drawStart)
   yStop = min(HEIGHT, drawEnd)
   yHeight = int(yStop - yStart)
   ```
2. Compute the corresponding part of the texture:

   ```
   pixelsPerTexel = lineHeight / texHeight
   colStart = int((yStart - drawStart) / pixelsPerTexel + .5)
   colHeight = int((yStop - yStart) / pixelsPerTexel + .5)
   ```
3. Extract the part-column from the texture using the [`subsurface`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159943/raycasting-algorithm-in-pygame#comment303065_159943) method:

   ```
   column = texture.subsurface((texX, colStart, 1, colHeight))
   ```
4. Take a copy (so we don't update the original) and multiply the colour using the [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) method with `BLEND_MULT`:

   ```
   column = column.copy()
   column.fill((c, c, c), special_flags=BLEND_MULT)
   ```
5. Scale it to the height at which we're going to draw it using [`transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale):

   ```
   column = pygame.transform.scale(column, (resolution, yHeight))
   ```
6. Blit it to the screen:

   ```
   SCREEN.blit(column, (x, int(yStart)))
   ```

I find that this change more than doubles the framerate, to about 40 fps.

As written above, this change causes some ugliness in the rendering of walls near the camera because of the way the computation of `yStart` causes the texels to line up with the screen edge. This can be avoided by recomputing `yStart` and `yHeight` after `colStart` and `colHeight`, like this:

```
# Recompute to ensure columns are truncated smoothly.
yStart = int(colStart * pixelsPerTexel + drawStart + .5)
yHeight = int(colHeight * pixelsPerTexel + .5)
```

(This also has the nice side-effect of reducing the amount of "pixel creep".)

Now that we've eliminated the inner loop, it's no longer obvious where to look for further improvements. So now would be a good time to run the profiler. But I think this is enough for one answer.

#### Revised code

This replaces the `for y in range(texHeight):` loop:

```
# Darken environment with distance.
# Faces with side=1 are darker to add to the 3D effect
c = max(1, (255.0 - rayLength * 27.2) * (1 - side * .25))

yStart = max(0, drawStart)
yStop = min(HEIGHT, drawEnd)
pixelsPerTexel = lineHeight / texHeight
colStart = int((yStart - drawStart) / pixelsPerTexel + .5)
colHeight = int((yStop - yStart) / pixelsPerTexel + .5)

yStart = int(colStart * pixelsPerTexel + drawStart + .5)
yHeight = int(colHeight * pixelsPerTexel + .5)

column = texture.subsurface((texX, colStart, 1, colHeight))
column = column.copy()
column.fill((c, c, c), special_flags=BLEND_MULT)
column = pygame.transform.scale(column, (resolution, yHeight))
SCREEN.blit(column, (x, yStart))
```

Comment: Thanks! This has really helped a lot, there are just a few things that I'd like to mention. I couldn't get your way of getting the frame rate to work properly, so instead I ran `print(CLOCK.get_fps())` which worked perfectly. And the variable `texStart` doesn't exist, I assumed you meant `yStart` but this did not work either. And although it isn't as good to just blit the entire column, as you were only bliting the part on-screen, I just ran the last part of the code that you provided to get it to work. But the program now runs at 60 frames per second for me, and so I am pleased!

Comment: Adding this to the code was enough to get it to work:`column = texture.subsurface((texX, 0, 1, texHeight))
            column = column.copy()
            column.fill((c, c, c), special_flags = BLEND_MULT)
            column = pygame.transform.scale(column, (resolution, int(lineHeight)))

            SCREEN.blit(column, (x, int(drawStart)))`

Comment: Sorry about the mistake — `texStart` should be `colStart`. For avoidance of doubt, I added the revised code to the post. The problem with your version (where you scale up to `lineHeight`) is that `lineHeight` can get arbitrarily large (when the wall is very close to the camera) and so the call to `scale` can take arbitrarily long (and use arbitrary amounts of memory). It's necessary to scale only the portion of the texture that is going to be drawn.

Comment: You started the answer by a good paragraph (I experienced that statement when I worked with Python and OpenCV )